# Hash Sum mismatch while update package index(indigo/ubuntu 14.04.04)

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed install guide(http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu)
while 1.4 Installation step(sudo apt-get update), I met this error.

`W:Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages Hash Sum mismatch`

And, the laptop can resolve the web page( http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages).

I tried to fix it with below link, but it is not working.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228493/hash-sum-mismatch-while-update-package-index(indigo/ubuntu-14.04.04)/) by [hughie](https://answers.ros.org/users/232/hughie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hughie](https://answers.ros.org/users/232/hughie/) on 2016-03-07**:
Ubuntu 14.04.03 is also same.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-08**:
Yes. The same ROS repositories are used for all of the 14.04.x versions of Ubuntu, so I would expect the same trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is usually a temporary issue, and happens when you download packages at the same time that a repository sync is happening. It should go away if you try again a few minutes later.

Are you using an HTTP proxy?

**Update**

This error means that the checksum on the Packages file ( http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages ) doesn't match the checksum that is listed in the Release file ( http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release ). I guess you could download both files and try to manually verify the checksums.

When I compute the checksums on the Packages file, I get:

```
$ wget http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
$ sha1sum Packages 
058296435aba9ad217d436d338c9a19a37e0df74  Packages
$ md5sum Packages 
e8f069b226d4fa7155e90ef02f3235ec  Packages
```

And these match the checksums listed in the Release file (these checksums will be out of date in a few days, so be sure to check against the most recent copy of the Release file, and not the checksums listed here).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hughie](https://answers.ros.org/users/232/hughie/) on 2016-03-07**:
Thank you for your answer. I don't use HTTP proxy and other Ubuntu package index are fine.
I also tried with China mirror(http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation/UbuntuMirrors). but, It has same problem.

**Comment by [hughie](https://answers.ros.org/users/232/hughie/) on 2016-03-08**:
It's working now. now checksum on the packages file and checksum that is listed in the Release file are matched. maybe the checksums is fixed in the server.
Thank you for helping me!